# Help with a simple bar plot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I have some data in a table; the first column has some names; the second column associates a "category" to each name, and the third column associates a "section" to each name. All entries are alphabetic.

Now I want to draw a simple bar plot showing the percentage of total names belonging to each one of the categories.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
{Name A}    {Category One}      {Section One}
{Name B}    {Category Two}      {Section Two}
{Name C}    {Category One}      {Section Two}
{Name D}    {Category Two}      {Section Three}
{Name E}    {Category One}      {Section One}
{Name F}    {Category Three}        {Section Three}
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{test.txt}\mydata

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
width=16cm, height=10.5cm,
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex1,y expr=\coordindex2]{\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this gives me:

[image]

So clearly I am misusing the specifications for the plot. What should I do to get the desired plot?

Comment: So in this case, you would want three bars, one for Category One that represents 50 %, one for Category Two that represents 33 %, and one for Category Three that represents 17 %?

Comment: @Jake Exactly..

Comment: Is this a feature of pgf 3? I ask because I looked at the documentation and `pgfplotstable` described itself in terms of specifically numeric data/tables whereas what you want is entirely non-numberic in with partially non-numeric out. [But I didn't read the documentation entire.]

Comment: @cfr No, not a feature of PGF 3.0 (at least not, as far as I know); since `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable` are so powerful, I thought a task like the one I propose should be relatively easy to implement with "native" toold from those packages.

Comment: You can, I think, sort and count the entries in the second column but that won't scale up if you have complicated tables with lots of different entries or it's just ugly :)

Comment: @percusse I see. In my case, there's only three different types of entries in the second column. Do you perhaps know if `datatool` can handle this kind of thing automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For three types (or a few), this can fly by counting; I produced more rows to test more items

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
{Name A}    {Category One}  
{Name B}    {Category Two}  
{Name C}    {Category One}  
{Name D}    {Category Two}  
{Name E}    {Category One}  
{Name F}    {Category Three}
{Name E}    {Category One}  
{Name F}    {Category Three}
{Name E}    {Category One}  
{Name F}    {Category Three}
{Name E}    {Category One}  
{Name F}    {Category Three}
{Name D}    {Category Three}
{Name D}    {Category Two}  
}\mydata
\def\mycollist{}
% Flatten 2nd col!
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{[index]1}\of\mydata\as\myentry{%
\edef\mycollist{\myentry,\mycollist}
}
% Count entries
\StrCount{\mycollist}{Category One}[\mycatone]
\StrCount{\mycollist}{Category Two}[\mycattwo]
\StrCount{\mycollist}{Category Three}[\mycatthree]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,ymin=0,
width=10cm, height=5.5cm,
xtick={1,2,3},
xticklabels={Category One,Category Two,Category Three}
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,\mycatone) (2,\mycattwo) (3,\mycatthree)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]